# How can you simplify the expression $\frac{(n+1)!}{k! \cdot (n-k+1)!}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, factorial

> $$\frac{(n+1)!}{k! \cdot (n-k+1)!}$$

I don't have any clue. Can $(n-k+1)!$ be simplified into $(n+1)!(k)!$?

I am not familiar enough with the symbol "$!$".

Comment: Relevant reading: [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) and [Binomial_coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: The symbol $!$ refers to [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Comment: i get n!(n+1)/k! (n-k)! (n-k+1) how do I get rid of the k in the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the binomial coefficient $\binom{n+1}{k}$.

Comment: how did you get to that?

Comment: The formula for $\binom{n}{k}$ is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.  If you substitute $n+1$ for $n$, you get the above.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $!$ is the factorial, it is defined as 
$$n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots 2\cdot 1 = \prod_{j=1}^n j.$$
The expression $\frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!}=\binom nk$ is also known as the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). There is a number of interesting properties of this quantity. Most intuitively, it is the number of ways to pick $k$ elements out of a set that contains $n$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

A concrete example might be helpful. Let $n = 4$ and $k = 3$. The expression can be expanded to
$$
\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 }{(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)(2 \cdot 1)}.
$$

Notice both the expressions in the denominator are shorter factorials, so you can quickly cancel the "tail" of the factorial in the numerator as
$$
\frac{5 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 1}
$$
or
$$
\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}.
$$
(Of course, more cancellation can be done with specific numbers, but I'm trying to mimic the general case where $n$ and $k$ are not specified.)

Back to general $n$ and $k$, we can simplify your original expression as either
$$
\frac{(n+1) \cdot n \cdots (k+1)}{(n+1-k)!}
$$
or
$$
\frac{(n+1) \cdot n \cdots (n+2-k)}{k!}.
$$
In the former, I cancelled the $k!$ "tail". In the latter, I cancelled the $(n+1-k)!$ "tail". Without more information about $n$ and $k$, this is the most cancellation one can hope for.